# How to solve numpy matrix multiplication error

Tags: python, numpy

```
w, b, X, Y = np.array([[1.],[2.]]), 2., np.array([[1.,2.,-1.],[3.,4.,-3.2]]), np.array([[1,0,1]])
w1 = w.T
print(np.matmul(X*w1))
```

This code gives the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (1,2)
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Matrix multiplication isn't defined unless the number of columns of the first operand is the same as the number of row as the second. Shape `(2,3)` and `(1,2)` can't be multiplied in that order, but they can in the opposite order. So maybe you want `np.matmul(w1, X)`?

Comment: `X*w1` is element wise product.  `matmul` is matrix product, but needs 2 arguments.  The error is in the * operation.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix multiplication is not your problem here. It is the multiplication you are trying to do: `X*w1`. This is not possible. If you want to multiply two arrays, they have to have the same shape or you can use broadcasting. But for broadcasting to work, all the axes, except one, have to have the same length. So that would not be possible in this case.

It seems what you are actually trying to do is matrix multiplication. This needs two matrices, so you cannot multiply them first. Also, for two matrices to be multiplied this way, the number of columns of the first matrix needs to equal the number of rows of the second. So, the following would work and is probably what you are trying to do:

```
np.matmul(w1, X)
```